# Client secret not provided in request error with Keycloak

Tags: keycloak

I am facing the following issue after changing Access Type to confidential for the server-side client. It was working fine with public type.

Here is my adapter setting:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:keycloak:1.1">
    <secure-deployment name="appWEB.war">
        <realm>demo</realm>
        <resource>app</resource>
        <public-client>true</public-client>
        <auth-server-url>http://localhost:8180/auth</auth-server-url>
        <ssl-required>EXTERNAL</ssl-required>
        <principal-attribute>preferred_username</principal-attribute>
        <use-resource-role-mappings>true</use-resource-role-mappings>
            <credential name="secret">b35f1121-93a4-4483-a70a-0048b95fd250</credential> 
    </secure-deployment>
</subsystem>
```

Here is the error found in log during login:

> [Server:node-00] 17:29:06,924 ERROR
>   [org.keycloak.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator] (default task-6)
>   failed to turn code into token [Server:-node-00] 17:29:06,924 ERROR
>   [org.keycloak.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator] (default task-6)
>   status from server: 400 [Server:node-00] 17:29:06,924 ERROR
>   [org.keycloak.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator] 
>   {"error":"unauthorized_client","error_description":"Client secret not provided in request"}

Any thoughts?

Comment: What is this ?        ` <auth-server-url>http://localhost:8180/auth</auth-server-url>` At least put exact code what you are using n application.

Comment: KC server on same box. ie both servers running on localhost. This is URL to Keycloak server & it works fine if  Access Type is public.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Error:

```
Client secret not provided in request
```

I guess, you didn't configure client secret in your app, which is required for confidential clients.

Comment: Would you share some link regarding how to  configure client secret in app? I just set the secret value got from KC in adapter, <credential name="secret">b35f1121-93a4-4483-a70a-0048b95fd250</credential>.

Comment: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#openid-connect-3
Probably also public-client: true is not correct in your case.

Comment: Yes, public-client: true is removed & this error gone but after login redirection to app shows error as there is no valid permission.

Comment: then check your web.xml file

Comment: did you find the solution? I'm facing the same "forbidden" issue

Comment: Yes, set client as confidential, remove public-client & set correct credential name="secret" value. This fixed the issue.

Comment: Would you please share your final adapter setting @ValsarajViswanathan

Comment: <realm>demo</realm>
<resource>app</resource>
<use-resource-role-mappings>true</use-resource-role-mappings>
<auth-server-url>https://<IP>:8543/auth</auth-server-url>
<ssl-required>EXTERNAL</ssl-required>
<principal-attribute>preferred_username</principal-attribute>
<credential name="secret"><secret></credential>